# Wordpress comments template returning every comment, instead of only the ones of the post;

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
    <?php
       $args = array(
        'status' => 'approve',
        'post_id' => get_the_ID()
    );

    // The comment Query
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
     
    // Comment Loop


    if ( $comments ) {
     foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        echo '<div class="e-comment__items">';
          echo '<div class="e-comment__items-item">';
            echo '<div class="imgPerfil">' . $comment->comment_author . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="autor">' . $comment->comment_author . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="horas">' . testeHora($comment->comment_date) . '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="content">' . $comment->comment_content . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    
     }
     
    } else {
     echo 'Seja o primeiro a comentar';
    }
       ?>
```

It should've returned only the comments that belong to each post, but instead it's returning every comment in every post.

I need to show only the comments that belong to each post, or show nothing at all.

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: At the single.php template

Comment: Where in single.php? Can you show us the code before this in your single.php?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. It was due to the post_id it was lacking. Thank you!